# How to delete .dbf file in oracle?

Tags: windows, oracle

I am trying to recreate a tablespace in Oracle and get the following error message:

```
  "created file already exists"
```

I am running the following script:

```
create smallfile tablespace dev_01 datafile 'C:\Oradata\db1\devdata\dev_01
.dbf' size 500M
```

Any ideas?  I have tried killing any sessions that were using the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle in Windows does not drop the datafile, despite the synax in the INCLUDING clause. You can manually delete it using Windows, or you can simply use:

```
CREATE SMALLFILE TABLESPACE dev_01 
       DATAFILE 'C:\Oradata\db1\devdata\dev_01.dbf' SIZE 500M REUSE;
```

This will reuse the existing file if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this command which complains that the tablespace does not exist:

```
DROP TABLESPACE dev_01 INCLUDING CONTENTS AND DATAFILES;
```

Comment: That's because the tablespace has been dropped. However, the datafile does not get dropped in Oracle/Windows.